# How to change styles of one element in a array in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to change styles of one element that I received from an API, when I render it, I need to change styles for example of the second element displayed, like a font-size bigger or italic etc, any idea that how can I implement this?, I supponse to use the index but I new in salesforce, any idea welcome.

```
API = { 
 data : [
   info_1 : { 
              v1= 'v1v1v1',
              v2= 'v2v2v2',
              v3= 'v3v3v3'
            },
   info_2 : {
              v1='aaaa',
              v2='bbbb',
              v3='cccc'
            },

        ]
}
```

in HTML LWC I render this

```
  <Template for:each={data} for:item='item' for:index='index'>
      <div class="box 1">{index}<h3 class={tiTleClass}>{item.info_1}=</h3></div>
      <div class="box 2">{item.info_2}</div> 
  </Template>
```

Result output would be:

```
             0 v1v1v1 =  aaaa 
             1 v2v2v2 =  bbbb   ---> I need to give style to this element!!
             2 v3v3v3 =  cccc
```

JS:

I will try this but doesn't work

@api index;

get tiTleClass (){
return this.index == 1 ? 'slds-text-heading_large' : 'slds-text-heading_small';
}

Comment: What have you tried? What part of it didn't work? Did you get any errors?

Comment: You need to ensure that the iterated JavaScript objects have a property that identifies how to render. A conventional approach is to add a property that identifies the CSS class to apply for the given entry in the rendering, with some CSS defined in the LWC that styles the output how you want.

Comment: Thanks you for your comments, I didn't try any solution to share, I'm lost with this, I will try to watch recommendations above suggested, thanks for your help

Comment: In the example you've provided, you know that v2 is the one that needs to be styled differently, so why aren't you just styling it differently? ie. to display the v2 stuff, you need to explicitly call it `{item.info_1.v2}`, so why not wrap it in whatever style you want?